# option item selection in Dialog menu

Tags: android

I have been running into some troubles recently and I think I need your help :).
I am currently trying to show a menu on top of a dialog, I know that it could be far easier to launch a new activity yet doing so would compell me to store/pass a lot of data.
I managed to show an optionmenu by writing a custom dialog and rewriting the oncreateOptionMenu method. 
My problem is I can't get any listener to these button, I tried to rewrite the onoptionitemselectedmethod but nothing happens.
Ps: my dialog is nearly full screen so i can't see the activity dialog (i didn't find any put on top method)

I would be glad to try any solution you could provide.

Thanks a lot

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,Menu.NONE,c.getString(R.string.home));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,4,Menu.NONE,c.getString(R.string.report));
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if(item.getItemId()==0){
        getOwnerActivity().startActivity(new Intent(c,Home.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    }
    else
        if(l>1)
            getOwnerActivity().startActivity(new Intent(c,report.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        else
            dismiss();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this little snippet out of my app helps you:

```
private static final int REFRESH_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  menu.add(0, REFRESH_ID, 0, R.string.menu_refresh).setIcon(R.drawable.and_refresh);
  return result;
}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case REFRESH_ID: {
      // Do whatever you want here!
      return true;  
    }
  }
  return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

As you can see, I've got constants for my menu-items. Those items get the Menu.First + n number as integer. For every item, I count it up. Easier, then change it everytime ;)
And in the onMenuItemSelected you can switch those constants easily.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer but it is not where my problem lies, i will try to make myself clear.
I have a Dialog which is roughly full screen.
I want a menu on top of it when the user press the menu button.
When I managed to get the menu with the method onCreateOptionsMenu on a custom dialog.
The program do not pass through onOptionsItemSelected when an button is clicked.
you're code would have been perfectly usefull if i wasn't in a Dialog.

Comment: At first i didn't see the difference between your code and mine. The fact is i was just misusing the function onOptionsItemSelected instead of onMenuItemSelected.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem :) Hope to see a few apps soon ;)

Comment: I agree that this does work, but I'm not sure why.  In an activity, you would override `onOptionsItemSelected` to handle an option menu choice.  For some reason, when implementing a custom menu in a dialog, the choice event is dispatched to `onMenuItemSelected` instead!